# Create Session with Android Java Firebase

Tags: java, android, session, firebase

I am using email and password. I have create user and authenticate user but I don't know how to add a session for this user.

For example, if the user logs into his/her account. He/she is able to delete the application's process on their phone when they do not want to use the app, then  get rid of the app's process and the session is should still be ongoing, therefore when they go back to their application they should still be logged in until he/she logs out (unauth).

I am having trouble making a session for a logged in user. I believe a token must be used but I have no idea how I should use it.

Login Activity:

```
Firebase user_data = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com"); 
user_data.authWithPassword(login_email.getText().toString(), login_pwd.getText().toString(), new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
@Override
public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
    System.out.println("User ID: " + authData.getUid() + ", Provider: " + authData.getProvider());
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    Intent toMainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(toMainActivity);  
  }
            @Override
public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                // there was an error
    System.out.println("ERROR.........................................");
     }
});
```

Heres a simple scenerio:
User logs in. (From Login class is being Intent to Main activity class)
User does not log out but delete app's process.
Later User decides to use the app.

My problem: When click on app, it brings the user back to the Login page whereas it should brought the user to the Main Activity page.

**Updated - Initialization**

I have initialize it's still not saving the logged in state.

> My problem: When click on app, it brings the user back to the Login page whereas it should brought the user to the Main Activity page.

Here's the Main Activity page:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase user_data = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com"); 
    user_data.addAuthStateListener(new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
            if (authData != null) {
                System.out.println("Authentication is currently working"); //this did print
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed authentication");
            }
        }
    });

    AuthData authData = user_data.getAuth();
    if (authData != null) {
        System.out.println("The state is: " + authData); //this did print
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }
```

I check the authentication and they seem to be fine but when I delete the process after logging in at the Main Activity it jumps back to the Login page when I reload the app.

The results for monitoring the auth data above:

working auth

> Authentication is currently working

state

> The state is: AuthData{uid='simplelogin:3', provider='password', token='***', expires='1426758087', auth='{provider=password, uid=simplelogin:3}', providerData='{email=du16493@gmail.com, isTemporaryPassword=false}'}
>
> Authentication is currently working

**SOLVED**

Just add the intent if authentication is currently running and it should straight back into the Main activity when the app first loads up on your phone at your first activity you called.

Here's the Login Activity page:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase user_data = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com"); 
    user_data.addAuthStateListener(new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
            if (authData != null) {
                System.out.println("Authentication is currently working"); //this did print
                Intent toMainActivity = new Intent( getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(toMainActivity);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed authentication");
            }
        }
    });

    AuthData authData = user_data.getAuth();
    if (authData != null) {
        System.out.println("The state is: " + authData); //this did print
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }
```

Comment: Can you expand on your question? It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: so I want to create a session for a logged in user. So for example. Lets say I logged in with my Android phone and but don't want to use this app so I click home button and deletes the app's process. Later I decide to use this app so when I open the app it should still be logged in but its not from my code given above.

Comment: As you stated above, the authentication is successfully being picked up again, but there's no code included in the `authStateListener` that shows any type of change to the current activity, UI, etc. You're logging the auth. state and show that the session has been reinstated, but where are you showing or hiding the login form?

Comment: I dont know how to hide the login, is it a built in android code?  So do I have to hide the login form inside authstatelistener?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - you need to have your code show or hide the login form appropriately, based upon authentication state.

Comment: do you know what I should use to hide the login page when the app first loads up, I have being googling some time but have not yet found anything...

Comment: nvm i got it working omg, im so such a noob :D thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for authentication sessions to be persisted across application restarts, you'll need to initialize the Firebase Android client library with you Android context:

From https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/setup.html:

> The Firebase library must be initialized once with an Android context.
>   This must happen before any Firebase reference is created or used. You
>   can add the Firebase setup code to your Android Application's or
>   Activity's onCreate method.
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate() {
>     super.onCreate();
>     Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
>     // other setup code
> }
> ```

The Firebase client will automatically be authenticated on subsequent application cold starts. To check authentication state, see [Firebase Android: Monitoring Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication).

Comment: thx for your reply, I am still having the same issue. I updated the answer and add in the main activity class. In my Login class I have initialize `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` also.